# How to split a string with value contains the delimiter also in java?

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I have a string with value - `String sData = "abc|def|\"de|er\"|123";` and I will need to split it with delimiter - "|". In this case, my expected result will be

```
abc
def
"de|er"
123
```

Below is my code

```
String sData = "abc|def|\"de|er\"|123";
    String[] aSplit = sData.split(sDelimiter);

    for(String s : aSplit) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

But it actually comes out the below result

```
abc
def
"de
er"
123
```

I have tried with this pattern - `String sData = "abc|def|\"de\\|er\"|123";` but it's still not returning my expected result.

Any idea how can I achieve my expected result?

Comment: I think that to handle this in general you will need some sort of parser functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
String sData = "abc|def|\"de|er\"|123";
    String[] aSplit = sData.split("\\|");

        for(int i = 0; i < aSplit.length; i++) {
            if(aSplit[i].startsWith("\"")) {
                if(aSplit[i+1].endsWith("\"")) {
                    aSplit[i] = aSplit[i] + "|" + aSplit[i+1];
                    aSplit[i+1] = "";
                }
            }
        }

    for(String s : aSplit) {
        if(!s.equals(""))
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

The output:

```
abc
def
"de|er"
123
```

Comment: expected is `"deer"` or `"de|er"`?

Comment: @RamanSahasi good point. Lemme fix that

Comment: Hi thanks Cardinal, this works for me. appreciated.

Comment: @chris no problem. Don't forget to vote on the answer ;)